# Counting ajaxcalls and get their status

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to count all the ajaxcalls made when a page loads and get the status of each one? I would like to create a progressbar that shows the page loading process (since its built up from different html files loaded using jquery ajax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two methods in jquery: ajaxStart() and ajaxStop(); you can increment a counter with ajaxStart() event and another one with ajaxStop(). Then you'll be able to see how many requests were finished and make the necessary changes.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    finishedCalls++;
    // update progress bar
});
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    startedCalls++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the ajaxSend event. So you can try:

```
var ajax_count = 0;
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  ajax_count++;
});
```